# Get part of string into variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables

i need to get part of string into variable. (note, i will always use exactly 4 names)

```
var names = "Andrew Peter Bob Mark"
```

I need to get the last one to

```
var last = "Mark"
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var last = names.split(/\s+/).pop(); // "Mark"
```

Explanation: `.split` splits a string on a given separator and returns an array. `/\s+/` is a regular expression for "one or more whitespaces" (space, tab, newline, etc). `.pop()` grabs the last value from the array that `.split` returns.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from Roatin Marth is correct, but in case if you need 4 times faster version (in IE) of same operation:

```
var last = names.substr(names.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

It is working without regular expressions and temp arrays - just with index operations of string.